# Merge rows using range in one column and math operator on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I know there are many threads on this `df.groupby` to merge rows with the *same value* in a column. But for the following situation, given this data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:00.274', 'value1': 123, 'value2': 21},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:00.374', 'value1': 101, 'value2': 33},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:01.294', 'value1':   7, 'value2': 12},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:02.002', 'value1':  42, 'value2': 10},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:02.039', 'value1':   1, 'value2': 34},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:03.00', 'value1':   2, 'value2': 41}])
```

I want to merge rows base on `timestamp`. The condition is: the benchmark time is at `second .0`, for eg `2021-05-28 14:02:01.000` is the benchmark. Any rows that fall between `2021-05-28 14:02:00.500` and `2021-05-28 14:02:01.500` should be grouped together where the `value1` and `value2` are the `max` in the group. The timestamp upper and lower boundary can be inclusive in either of these `[ )` or `(  ]`.

For this eg., the expected output is:

```
df_merge = pd.DataFrame([{'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:00.000', 'value1': 123, 'value2': 33},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:01.000', 'value1':   7, 'value2': 12},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:02.000', 'value1':  42, 'value2': 34},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:03.00', 'value1':   2, 'value2': 41}])
```

Here, row `0` and `1` are merged into one, row `3` and `4` are merged into one.

The values in column `timestamp` is of `datetime64[ns]` type.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

try:

```
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
#convert 'timestamp' column to datetime
```

Finally make use of `groupby()` and `pd.Grouper()`:

```
out=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='1s')).max().reset_index()
```

**OR**

via `assign()`,`floor()` and `groupby()`:

```
out=df.assign(timestamp=df['timestamp'].dt.floor('1s')).groupby('timestamp',as_index=False).max()
```

**OR**

via `set_index()` and `resample()`:

```
out=df.set_index('timestamp').resample('1s').max().reset_index()
```

output of `out`:

```
    timestamp             value1    value2
0   2021-05-28 14:00:00     123     33
1   2021-05-28 14:00:01     7       12
2   2021-05-28 14:00:02     42      34
3   2021-05-28 14:00:03     2       41
```