# Remove redundant rows when merging using timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow-up question from [this thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062187/merge-rows-using-range-in-one-column-and-math-operator-on-other-columns/68062282#68062282).

The solutions in there work. However, using a frequency `1s`, the `grouping` operation creates additional empty rows of seconds in between:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:00.274', 'value1': 123, 'value2': 21},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:00.374', 'value1': 101, 'value2': 33},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:01.294', 'value1':   7, 'value2': 12},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:02.002', 'value1':  42, 'value2': 10},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-05-28 14:00:02.039', 'value1':   1, 'value2': 34},
                   {'timestamp': '2021-06-28 14:00:03.00', 'value1':   2, 'value2': 41}])
```

For the data frame above, a massive number of redundant rows are created between the last two timestamps `2021-05-28 00:02.00` and `2021-06-28 00:03.00` at the frequency of `1s`.

How to restrict to just grouping whatever is in the source data frame and not introducing redundant rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove `timestamp` from original:

```
#DatetimeIndex
df1 = df.groupby(df.pop('timestamp').dt.floor('1s')).max()

#column timestamp
#df1 = df.groupby(df.pop('timestamp').dt.floor('1s')).max().reset_index()
```

What is simplier like:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/68062217/2901002
out=df.assign(timestamp=df['timestamp'].dt.floor('1s')).groupby('timestamp',as_index=False).max()
```

For another solutions is possible use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) if not exist missing values in original data:

```
df=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='timestamp',freq='1s')).max().dropna().reset_index()
```